# Assign max width to layout in landscape like Gmail app compose page

Tags: android

I'm creating compose page just like gmail app, how do I create layout that limits the maxWidth of activity/fragment?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="7dp">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/title_text"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/title_hint"
                    android:padding="7dp"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/contents"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/contents_hint"
                    android:padding="7dp"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: And you did any thing yet? I mean where is your layout file?

Comment: My layout is bare bones linearlayout with vertical gravity, that won't make any sense.

Comment: replace android:layout_width="0dp" with android:layout_width="fill_parent" in both edittext. and remove android:layout_weight="1" from second edittext.

Comment: Now how will that limit the width? BTW I added 0dp coz I was testing an inline horizontal LL for each line. Added here by mistake. Android layout-opt recommends using width=0dp when using weights.